# How to redirect the url

Tags: jquery, html, servlets

I am not sure what would be the exact technical term for this but i wanted to access a file which is avail in server(`Apache Tomcat`). i just wanted to type this in browser e.g.

`http://localhost:8080/myProjectName/eng` :
***but this should refer as. `http://localhost:8080/myProjectName/english.html` ***

`http://localhost:8080/myProjectName/hin` :
***but this should refer as. `http://localhost:8080/myProjectName/hindi.html` ***

my project structure is

```
myProjectName
          |
       webContent
           |
           |----WEB-INF
           |      |_ _ _ web.xml
           |
           |--- english.html
           |--- hindi.html
```

is there any way to get the possible result by writing something in web.xml.

```
Environment : java servlet html js jQuery tomcat6.0
```

Comment: Do you want to redirect the URL (so that the target URL reappears in browser address bar) or do you want to rewrite/forward the URL (so that the original URL remains in browser address bar)?

Comment: @BalusC i want the original URL remains in browser address bar.

Comment: @BalusC: i just wanted to let you know that given solution of Bibhaw is working for me although i'm not sure it's standard sol'n or not. please confirm if possible.

Comment: Okay, you thus want a rewrite/forward and **not** a redirect, in contrary what you asked in the question. The answer of Bibhaw is fine. An alternative would be http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/ which allows for more simple configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i am understanding your question, here is the solution :

1. What you need to do? file configuration
2. use `<jsp-file>` mapping instead of `<servlet-class>`

`http://localhost:8080/myProjectName/eng`  Just define mapping in `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>config</servlet-name>
   <jsp-file>/english.html</jsp-file>   /* referential page */
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>config</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/eng</url-pattern>     /* url pattern */
</servlet-mapping>
```